# Error Adding Geodatabase Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, vector-layer

I am trying to add a geodatabase (.gdb) vector layer into QGIS but I am running into an error. It says the .gdb file is not a valid or recognized data source.

[image]

I have spoken with the agency that maintains the file and they said it should work - it works fine on their end in ArcGIS Desktop. It's a version 9.3 .gdb file.

I have successfully opened and edited other .gdb files in QGIS. I use Directory --> OpenFileGDB. I am using QGIS version 2.18.15. What could be causing the problem now?

A link to download the GDB file is here: https://vgin.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=29627d7c051a47dc8ce71b4484531ab3

Here is a screenshot of the files within the .gdb file. Is something missing?

[image]

Comment: "it works fine on their end." In QGIS? Or ArcGIS?

Comment: It works for them in ArcGIS

Comment: @csft306 - Could you share your dataset or provide a link to it if it is available to the public?

Comment: @joseph - Just edited the post to include the link. Thanks.

Comment: Did you, @csft306, get to open the .gdb? I had the same problem with another dataset, tried yours and I am seeing the same problem. Running QGIS 2.18 64bit with GDAL/ORG 2.2.4 and QGIS 3.4.0 32bit with GDAL/ORG 2.3.2 on Win7.

Comment: @csft306 Wow I actually just found this thread because I am having the EXACT same problem with the EXACT same parcel dataset form Virginia (although I think I am looking at a more up-to-date set from 2019). Did you ever find a solution?!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of QGIS you are using but try opening it using the "Directory", "OpenFileGDB" options:

[image]

Comment: This is the method I used and got the error. Directory --> OpenFileGDB...

Comment: I'm using QGIS version 2.18.15

Answer (score 0):

Try 'dragging & dropping' the files into QGIS. Not from the QGIS browser panel but directly from a file explorer window into the QGIS map canvas. I remember having a similar problem a while ago and the 'drag & drop' method worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this didn't work either.